# How do you inject jdbiFactory DAOs into a Dropwizard Command?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm starting to work with [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/) and I'm trying to create a [Command](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/core/#commands) that requires to use the database. If someone is wondering why I'd want to do that, I can provide good reasons, but this is not the point of my question anyway. It's about dependency inversion and Service initialization and run phases in Dropwizard.

Dropwizard encourages to use its [DbiFactory to build DBI instances](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/jdbi/) but in order to get one, you need an `Environment` instance and/or the database configuration:

```
public class ConsoleService extends Service<ConsoleConfiguration> {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    new ConsoleService().run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<ConsoleConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.setName("console");
    bootstrap.addCommand(new InsertSomeDataCommand(/** Some deps should be here **/));
  }

  @Override
  public void run(ConsoleConfiguration config, Environment environment) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, config.getDatabaseConfiguration(), "postgresql");
    // This is the dependency I'd want to inject up there
    final SomeDAO dao = jdbi.onDemand(SomeDAO.class); 
  }
}
```

As you can see, you have the configuration for your Service and its Environment in its `run()` method, but commands need to be added to the Service's bootstrap in its `initialize()` method.

So far, I've been able to achieve this by extending [ConfiguredCommand](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/maven/apidocs/com/yammer/dropwizard/cli/ConfiguredCommand.html) in my Commands and creating `DBI` instances inside their `run()` methods, but this is a bad design, because [dependencies should be injected into the object instead of creating them inside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

I'd prefer to inject DAOs or any other dependencies of my Commands through their constructor, but this seems currently impossible to me, as the `Environment` and the configuration are not accesible in Service initialization, when I need to create and add them to its bootstrap.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you use the [EnvironmentCommand](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.7.1/dropwizard-core/apidocs/io/dropwizard/cli/EnvironmentCommand.html)?

Comment: Thanks! That didn't exist when I posted the question... i think :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I use Guice with Dropwizard. Inside your run() method add the line

```
Guice.createInjector(new ConsoleModule());
```

Create the class ConsoleModule

```
public class ConsoleModule extends AbstractModule {

 public  ConsoleModule(ConsoleConfiguration consoleConfig)
 {
     this.consoleConfig = consoleConfig;
 }

 protected void configure()
{
   bind(SomeDAO.class).to(SomeDAOImpl.class).in(Singleton.class)
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this is a solution to my problem, I'd like to find a solution without the need of a DI container such as Guice. Thanks anyway!