# How to access the Guice Module instance from application(dropwizard) run() method

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard, morphia

I need to set an attribute to my guice module from the run() method of my application. How do I get hold of the module instance.

How will this guy implement his run() method - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28088545/8788071

I tried doing - SalModule module = guiceBundle.getInjector().getInstance(SalModule.class);

but its trying to create a new instance as the constructer requires arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remember the reference of the guice module created in the initialize() method of the application, when passing it to create a guice bundle.